# Nespresso Virtuoline long pull vs short pull

Tags: espresso, nespresso

While using a Nespresso Virtuoline, the machine seems to read a barcode on the capsules which tells it how much water to use.  The high intensity espressos seem to give you a very small quantity (about .3 oz with maybe .2 oz crema).

I was wondering if its possible to make a long pull with the virtuoline?  Or do the capsules simply not contain enough coffee so it becomes watered down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a little bit research on the [Nespresso FAQ](https://www.nespresso.com/us/en/service-faq) and found the following:

> **VertuoLine - Can I make a Coffee that is larger than 230ml / 7.77 oz.?**
>
> Specific extraction parameters are set for each blend and each coffee
> is developed from the interplay between the extraction parameters and
> the coffee blends to guarantee the best result in-cup. However, the
> machine enables brewing larger than 230ml / 7.77 oz. (to 500ml / 17
> oz.). Check your Machine Manual or call our Technical Specialist via
> our toll-free number.

It looks like it is possible, but depending on your machine type.

Comment: There is a way to change the setting, yes.  You can do it on the pixie line, too